# How to obtain the handler for a secondary activity started by a first activity using an intent?

Tags: multithreading, android-intent, android-activity, handler, looper

I have a main activity in my project from which i am starting a secondary activity using an intent. On a separate thread, I want to get the handler of the second activity for send some control messages to the second activity. How can i receive the handler for the second activity which i have started using an intent?

Answer (score 0):

I would begin sending messages to this second activity, when it has been already created. That means, I would create a `Handler` object in the `onCreate()` method of this second activity, and pass that handler to the thread you want to send the message from.